# Lose Calm, if you make a creature attack does it become tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Lose Calm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lose%20Calm) says

> Gain control of target creature until end of turn. Untap that creature. It gains haste until end of turn and can't be blocked this turn except bye two or more creatures.

So it says untap the creature, but that is so I can attack them with it, so do I tap the creature when its back in their control if I used it to attack them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A creature being tapped or untapped is completely independent of who controls it. When Lose Calm resolves, you become the creature's controller and the creature untaps if it was tapped. Then you can do whatever you want with it, including attack with it. After that, once your turn ends, the creature returns to your opponent's control, in whatever state it is in.

Comment: So in practice, the creature returns to your opponent's control tapped, but since this is the start of their turn they will shortly be allowed to untap it again, in the same phase where they untap the rest of their permanents.